# How can I set the value of column equals (column1 * column2)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server Management Studio, let's say I have 3 columns in my `tbl_product`, `column1` (`nchar(60)`), `column2` (`nchar(60)`), and in my `column3` I want its value to be the result of (`column1 * column2`), how can I do that?

I saw a "Formula" in the column properties, but I'm not sure how to set a formula there, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Note: let's just set the column1 & column2's datatype to `nchar`.

Comment: Formula should be `column1*column2`.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) for more info.

Comment: how can I parse the column1 and column2 in the formula, it is in nchar datatype

Comment: The computed column's data type will be set automatically.  Please read the link I posted.  It has a large section about how it handles different data types.

Comment: What do you expect as the result from multiplying two string values??

Comment: yes that is what I wanted , those 2 colums will always return 2 decimal string, and I want the column 3 to display in 2 decimal values too.

Comment: If those are decimal strings then you need to use `CONVERT` to cast them to the correct datatype first.

Comment: So if those are always **numerical values** - why are you storing them as `nchar(60)` ?? First of all - **wrong datatype** - secondly: why on earth in **Unicode** string (2 bytes per character) - and thirdly: why the fixed length of 60 characters which will be padded up with spaces always?? If it looks like a number, quacks like a number, smells like a number - it ***IS*** a number and then **store it as such** using `decimal(p,s)` datatype instead of `nchar(60)`. Doing so also allows you to easily multiply the two values without conversions.....

Comment: @marc_s okay , I will set it with the proper datatype , and may I know what is the first and second parameter for decimal(p,s) stands for?

Comment: A quick peak at this wildly underused thing called [***documentation***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) shows you: `p` stands for precision - total number of digits, and `s` stands for scale, meaning the number of digits after the decimal point (part of p). So `decimal(10,4)` is **10 digits in all**, 4 of which after the decimal point (thus 6 before the decimal point)

Comment: Okay , thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Presuming both columns are strings that represent decimals set your Formula to this:

`CONVERT(decimal,column1) * CONVERT(decimal,column2)`

To change how the column is displayed simply change your `SELECT` statements.  The column data will always be "stored" as accurate as possible.

Try running this:

`SELECT CAST(column3 as decimal(10,2)) As ComputedColumn FROM tbl_product`

In the above statement the cast means "show me 10 digits in total, and 2 digits after the decimal point".  You can change those numbers to whatever you'd like.

Comment: thanks , its working , but how can I make it display in 2 decimal places

Comment: @NicoTing Can you be more specific?

Answer (score -1):

You can sum two columns using transact sql while defining your table.

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Products   
(  
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL  
  , QtyAvailable smallint  
  , UnitPrice money  
  , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice  
);  

-- Insert values into the table.  
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (QtyAvailable, UnitPrice)  
VALUES (25, 2.00), (10, 1.5);  

-- Display the rows in the table.  
SELECT ProductID, QtyAvailable, UnitPrice, InventoryValue  
FROM dbo.Products;
```

[Microsoft Docs link for Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: This is no different than doing it from SSMS.  Setting Formula on `InventoryValue` to `QtyAvailable * UnitPrice` does the exact same thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
 ( [Test1] [nchar(10)] NULL,    
   [Test2] [nchar(10)] NULL, 
   [Total] AS (cast ([a] as int)+  cast(  [b] as int))
  ) ON [PRIMARY] 

GO 

  INSERT INTO dbo.Test ( test1, test2 ) VALUES 
   ( '1', --     test1 - int 
     '2' --      test2 - int 
  ) 

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test 
Results: 
Test1 test2 total
1         2       3
```